# Non-diagonalizable compact operators and the trace-class condition

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, trace

For a compact operator $A$ on a Hilbert space, it is said that $A$ is **trace-class** if for some (and hence any) orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, the series 
$$s_k = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\big\langle |A|e_n,e_n \big\rangle$$
is convergent.

If $A$ is diagonalizable, then it is very easy to see that, for large enough $t \in \mathbb{N}$, the operator $A^t$ is trace class.
Is this necessarily true for a non-diagonalizable compact operator?

Comment: Your definition of trace-class is wrong. You need $|A|$ there, as stated it is easy to construct both compact and non-compact, not trace-class, operators satisfying your definition.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for pointing out the error. Do you mean it should satisfy
$s_k == \sum_{n=1}^k \left<|A|(e_n),e_n \right>
$ is a convergent sequence?

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: I have fixed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you think that $A^t$ is trace class for sufficiently large $t$ if $A$ is diagonalizable? What if the eigenvalues are $\lambda_n = \frac{1}{\log(n+1)}$?

Comment: Yes, of course! If the eigenvaluesgo slowly ebough to $0$, then no power raising can help it to converge!